# Remote shutter release for Sony A7rii

Tags: sony, remote, shutter-release, sony-a7ii

I'm looking for a remote release for Sony A7Rii.  As far as I can tell there are none on the market and the only way is via the PlayMemories app.  Unfortunately my phone is a Motorolo E which is not compatible - it won't connect to the camera and is listed as not compatible in the PlayMemories documentation.  So my question is, what is the most cost effective way to get a remote release?  Is the only way to buy a new phone?

Comment: Search for "Sony a7 shutter release" on Amazon, anything that has a micro-usb port will work. I personally use the Fotga LCD Timer with my a7s and it works perfectly.

Comment: Another option for controlling it from a phone is TriggerTrap. Though not cheap.  http://www.triggertrap.com/

Answer (score 2):

The [Sony website](http://www.sony.com/electronics/interchangeable-lens-camera-products/t/accessories?accessoriesfor=ILCE-7RM2) lists a few non-app-based remote release options for the α7R II, namely the RMT-DSLR2 Wireless Remote Commander, the RM-VPR1 Remote Control with Multi-Terminal Cable, and the RM-SPR1 Remote Commander.

Comment: LOL - i think I looked at that page and didn't scroll to the bottom - still, the one with the locking button for bulbing is bloomin' expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PlayMemories App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sony.playmemories.mobile) provided you upgrade the camera firmware to 4.x or a [camera app](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-F00002) which shots when the viewfinder is obscured